# Is there a proper way to cache SVG sprite?

Tags: caching, svg, optimization, frontend

I would like to cache my SVG sprite to prevent 'jumping' effect on page reload, now I achieved this via localStorage, but it doesn't look neatly and correct. I wonder, is there a proper or just more elegant way to cache SVG sprite?

Answer (score 0):

The use of the local storage can be a part of a solution.

Check out the [Caching SVG Sprite in localStorage](https://osvaldas.info/caching-svg-sprite-in-localstorage) thread to learn more on how to cache the entire sprite file as static content.